# Python script: How to chop the output to a limited line size?

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, text-processing

I am using the python script for separating the domain from the respective emails and then grouping emails as per their respective domain. The following script work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]


for f in os.listdir(dr):
    write = []
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    lines = [[l.strip(), l.split("@")[-1].strip()] for l in open(file).readlines()]
    lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
    for item, occurrence in groupby(lines, itemgetter(1)):
        func = [s[0] for s in list(occurrence)]
        write.append(item+","+",".join(func))
    open(os.path.join(dr, "grouped_"+f), "wt").write("\n".join(write))
```

I used : `python3 script.py /path/to/input files`
The input I gave was a list of emails and got the out as:

```
domain1.com,gemail1@domain1.com,email2@domain.com
domain2.com,email1@domain2.com,email2@domain2.com,email3@domain2.com
```

But what the problem  am facing is because of the MongoDB limit. As MongoDB has limit of 16 MB of document size and single line in my output file is considered as 1 document by MongoDB and the line size should not go beyond 16 MB.
So what I want to have is the result should get limited to 21 emails per domain and if the domain has more emails then it should be printed on a new line with the rest emails (again if emails are exceeding 21 then newline with same domain name). I cam store duplicate data in the mongoDB.

So the final output should be something like the following:

```
domain1.com,email1@domain1.com,email2@domain1.com,... email21@domain1.com
domain1.com,email22@domain1.com,.....
domain2.com,email1@domain2.com,....
```

The dot (.) in the above example represents many text, which I chopped to make it simple to understand.
Hope this clarify my problem and hoping to get a solution for it.

Comment: You could split the list of emails into chunks of 21 elements using `[lst[i:i+21] for i in range(0, len(lst), 21]` and then convert that list into your output lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New version

The script you posted indeed groups the emails by domain, with no limit in number. Below a version that will group emails by domain, but split the found list into arbitrary chunks. Each chunk will be printed into a line, starting with the corresponding domain.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby, islice
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]
size = 3

def chunk(it, size):
    it = iter(it); return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(it, size)), ())

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    # list the files
    with open(os.path.join(dr, "chunked_"+f), "wt") as report: 
        file = os.path.join(dr, f)
        # create a list of email addresses and domains, sort by domain
        lines = [[l.strip(), l.split("@")[-1].strip()] for l in open(file).readlines()]
        lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
        # group by domain, split into chunks
        for domain, occurrence in groupby(lines, itemgetter(1)):
            adr = list(chunk([s[0] for s in occurrence], size))
            # write lines to output file
            for a in adr:
                report.write(domain+","+",".join(a)+"\n")
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `chunked_list.py`
- In the head section, set the chunk size:

  ```
  size = 5
  ```
- Run the script with the directory as argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/chunked_list.py /path/to/files
  ```

  It wil then create an edited file of each of the files, named `chunked_filename`, with the (chunked) grouped emails.

#### What it does

The script takes as input a directory with files like:

```
email1@domain1
email2@domain1
email3@domain2
email4@domain1
email5@domain1
email6@domain2
email7@domain1
email8@domain2
email9@domain1
email10@domain2
email11@domain1
```

Of each file, it creates a copy, like:

```
domain1,email1@domain1,email2@domain1,email4@domain1
domain1,email5@domain1,email7@domain1,email9@domain1
domain1,email11@domain1
domain2,email3@domain2,email6@domain2,email8@domain2
domain2,email10@domain2
```

(set cunksize = 3)

Comment: @JafferWilson You're welcome. If the input file possibly includes white lines or if the directory possibly also includes directories, please mention, we need to set an escape then.

Comment: I don't think there is any white space in the file. There are no recursive directories for sure.

Answer (score 1):

To support arbitrary large directories and files, you could [use `os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) receiving files one by one and processing the files line by line:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

def emails_with_domain(dirpath):
    for entry in os.scandir(dirpath):
        if not entry.is_file():
            continue  # skip non-files
        with open(entry.path) as file:
            for line in file:
                email = line.strip()
                if email:  # skip blank lines
                    yield email.rpartition('@')[-1], email  # domain, email
```

To group email addresses by domain, no more than 21 emails per line, you could [use `collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

dirpath = sys.argv[1]
with open('grouped_emails.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    emails = defaultdict(list)  # domain -> emails
    for domain, email in emails_with_domain(dirpath):
        domain_emails = emails[domain]
        domain_emails.append(email)
        if len(domain_emails) == 21:
            print(domain, *domain_emails, sep=',', file=output_file)
            del domain_emails[:]  # clear

    for domain, domain_emails in emails.items():
        print(domain, *domain_emails, sep=',', file=output_file)
```

Note:

- all emails are saved to the same file
- lines with the same domain are not necessarily adjacent

See [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/4279)

Comment: Some good thought. I will try this too. :)